# Referencing System.Data.DataSetExtensions.dll from unity3D

Tags: c#, linq, unity-game-engine

I need to reference to System.Data.DataSetExtensions.dll to use Linq To DataSet

I am running this piece of code:

```
DataTable dt = _dataSetCache.Tables["table0"];

var query = from d in dt.AsEnumerable()
            orderby d.Field<int>("INSTANCES")
            select d;
```

and getting this error

> The type arguments for method
>   `System.Linq.Enumerable.AsEnumerable(this
>   System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable)' cannot be inferred from the
>   usage. Try specifying the type arguments explicitly

How do I reference to make AsEnumerable available for my datatable in unity3D

Comment: OK. maybe my question is not clear enough. How do i reference to System.Data.DataSetExtensions.dll from Unity3D

Answer (score 0):

For those who are also facing this problem but cant find any solution online, here's the solution:

Just like how you add System.Data.dll to your unity project, grab the dll from this path:

.\Unity\Editor\Data\Mono\lib\mono\2.0

Comment: But how do you add System.Data.dll to your project?...